# Any structure interface

Tags: c++, design-patterns, data-structures, macros

Please, give me some clues concerning this matter. Thank you in advance and sorry if my explanation seems a bit confusing.

Suppose I have some struct

```
struct Some
{
  DataTypeA a;
  DataTypeB b;
  ...etc.
};
```

and I have this interface:

```
class AnyStruct
{
public:
  using Variant = boost::variant<boost::blank, DataTypeA, DataTypeB, ...etc.>;
  using StringArr = std::vector<std::string>;

  virtual StringArr fieldNames() = 0;
  virtual Variant getValue(const std::string & fieldName) = 0;
};
```

Futher I want to implement this interface to have possibility to access Some fields using string names like this:

```
class SomeStruct : public AnyStruct
{
  Some m_some;

public:
  SomeStruct(const Some & some);

  /**
   * Function fieldNames returns vector {"a", "b", ...etc.}. Please, see the Some 
   * structure definition above.
   */
  virtual StringArr fieldNames();

  /**
   * 1. Function getValue with parameter "a" returns m_some.a wrapped in boost::variant
   * 2. Function getValue with parameter "b" returns m_some.b wrapped in boost::variant
   * ...etc.
   */
  virtual Variant getValue(const std::string & fieldName);
};
```

May be there is a some elegant solution or design pattern for this case? I will be very grateful for any advices.

**UPD1:** 
May be it can be done using macroses.

Comment: Yes, I know about std::map. But, the problem is how can I effectively transform any c-like structure to such a map first? I meant something like this.

Comment: Are you trying to implement reflection yourself?

Comment: There's nothing elegant. You'd have to specifically code it for each struct type.

Comment: @Klaas van Gend Yes, I am. But I have got a very combersome solution.

Comment: @Fred Larson Can you give me some very short example, please?

Comment: if you need reflection, why not use a language that has reflection?

Comment: @stark Which language do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a macro like this:

```
#define FIELDS( TOK ) \
  TOK(a), TOK(b), TOK(c), TOK(d)
```

that lists all of the variables you want to reflect over.  Do this in your cpp file, because who wants to expose this ugly?

To use:

```
#define STR2(X) #X
#define STR(X) STR2(X)
#define TOK_NAME(X) STR(X)


StringArr SomeStruct::fieldNames() {
  static char const*const names[] = {
    FIELDS(TOK_NAME)
  };
  return { std::begin(names), std::end(names) };
}

#define TOK_GET_MAP(X) \
  { STR(X), +[](SomeStruct* ptr)->AnyStruct{ return ptr->m_some.X; } }

Variant SomeStruct::getValue(const std::string& fieldName) {
  using get_map = std::map< std::string, AnyStruct(*)(SomeStruct*) >;
  static const get_map table = {
    FIELDS(TOK_GET_MAP)
  };
  auto it = get_map.find(fieldName);
  if (it != get_map.end()) return it->second(this);
  return boost::blank;
}
```

or somesuch.